# Background color does not display in InputField unless Appearance option is also specified

Tags: color, mac-os-x, inputfield

I get the same behavior for v10.1.0, v.10.0.2 and v.9 with OS X (10.9.5) :

No background color is displayed in `InputField` if I just set properly the option. For example, the background just remains white if I do :

```
InputField[1, Background -> Yellow]

InputField[2, FieldSize -> 5, Background -> Yellow]
```

[image]

I just find out that, it finally works only if the `Appearance` option is also explicitly set, like in :

```
InputField[3, Appearance -> "Framed", Background -> Yellow]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get this behavior under Windows 7.

Comment: That has always been the case on OS X AFAIK. Probably a bug bug not a major issue.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I did not find any report for this on Stack exchange ...

Comment: it may not have been listed here before because it is not seen as a major issue.